# How to implement customized tab controls in java

Tags: java, swing, custom-component, jtabbedpane

I want a tab control like this[image]

The tab which is exactly in the picture is used by me in a C# project. This is a component offered by componentone studio with many custom options. But i can't find any plugins for java which can do things like this. Look and Feel doesn't work good at all. Can anyone tell me how to add stylish tab control to my application. As i am new to java please give me a detailed answer. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's **Tabbed Panes**, [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tabbedpane.html).

[`JTabbedPane`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTabbedPane.html) class.

Code example for page:

```
JTabbedPane tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane();
ImageIcon icon = createImageIcon("images/middle.gif");

JComponent panel1 = makeTextPanel("Panel #1");
tabbedPane.addTab("Tab 1", icon, panel1,
                  "Does nothing");
tabbedPane.setMnemonicAt(0, KeyEvent.VK_1);

JComponent panel2 = makeTextPanel("Panel #2");
tabbedPane.addTab("Tab 2", icon, panel2,
                  "Does twice as much nothing");
tabbedPane.setMnemonicAt(1, KeyEvent.VK_2);

JComponent panel3 = makeTextPanel("Panel #3");
tabbedPane.addTab("Tab 3", icon, panel3,
                  "Still does nothing");
tabbedPane.setMnemonicAt(2, KeyEvent.VK_3);

JComponent panel4 = makeTextPanel(
        "Panel #4 (has a preferred size of 410 x 50).");
panel4.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(410, 50));
tabbedPane.addTab("Tab 4", icon, panel4,
                      "Does nothing at all");
tabbedPane.setMnemonicAt(3, KeyEvent.VK_4);

protected JComponent makeTextPanel(String text) {
    JPanel panel = new JPanel(false);
    JLabel filler = new JLabel(text);
    filler.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
    panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 1));
    panel.add(filler);
    return panel;
}

protected static ImageIcon createImageIcon(String path) {
    java.net.URL imgURL = TabbedPaneDemo.class.getResource(path);
    if (imgURL != null) {
        return new ImageIcon(imgURL);
    } else {
        System.err.println("Couldn't find file: " + path);
        return null;
    }
}
```

[Complete source example](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/components/TabbedPaneDemoProject/src/components/TabbedPaneDemo.java).

Comment: Tnx, can you please tell How to make the Tabbed Panes semi transparent?

Comment: check this topic: http://www.coderanch.com/t/600541/GUI/java/JtabbedPane-transparency